# React: this is not defined in async callback function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I have been on this for long now please I need assistance. 
Am trying to make a call to an API link and I have an array of data to make the call as parameters to the call.
And After the call has been made I want to set the component state to the result gotten.

```
let animals = ['cats','goats'] ;
async.each(animals, function(item, cb){
  axios.get(`http://api.com?keyword=${item}`)
    .then(res=> {
        apiData.push(res.data)
        this.setState({
          stateData: apiData 
        });
     });
   })
```

Comment: Why set state each time? Why not just set state for the last argument?

Comment: the stateData is not working, it show this is not definded

Comment: @user3424387 you have to use an arrow function (cf. my answer)

Comment: @duhaime Your edit to the original question manipulated the initial meaning and intention of the question, please don't do this in the future. It's misleading.

Comment: @mxdi9i7 I changed the title to reflect the user's error reported in their comment above. Please see their comment.

Answer (score 1):

`async.each` only makes sense if you want to execute one request after another, and then you have to call `cb()` so that the chain continues:

```
 async.each(array, (item, cb) => { // <- arrow func!
   axios.get(`/http://api.com?keyword=${item}`)
   .then(res => {
     apiData.push(res.data);
     this.setState({ stateData: apiData });
     cb(); // <---
   });
});
```

Or to execute all in parallel (which is probably much faster):

```
 const promises = array.map(item => axios.get(`/http://api.com?keyword=${item}`).then(res => res.data));

 Promise.all(promises).then(stateData => {
   this.setState({ stateData });
 });
```

PS: You should always handle errors in a promise, so just attach a `.catch(/*..*/)` to the chain ...,

Comment: ok I think i did that before but got lost let say `cb()` is where I set the state of the stateData.

`cb(apiData ){this.setState({ stateData: apiData });}`

Comment: Also Very Correct

Answer (score -1):

Use arrow function for both `forEach` and api request callback, that will prevent javascript re-assigning the value of `this` during your callback chain.

More info about arrow functions in ES6 read: https://codeburst.io/javascript-arrow-functions-for-beginners-926947fc0cdc

Comment: can you give an instance

Comment: using `forEach` is still aysnc so you can't get the value after the .`const animals = ['cat', 'dog']; let apiData = []; animals.forEach((pets)=>axios.get(`https://www.petshouse/info${city}`).then(res => apiData.push(res.data))); console.log(apiData)`

Comment: The result is `[]`

Comment: @user3424387 You can't just edit the original question and ocntext and then downvote my response that answers to your original question. The context of the original question was regarding `this` being undefined. I pointed out that you were using function keyword instead of arrow function in the forEach callback, which was why your `this` reference was not pointing to the component. Although your usage of array async requests is also wrong, it was out of scope of your original question and thus I did not write my answer based on that.

Comment: No I did not do that I did not edit my question nor change the topic, scroll up you will see edited by duhaime and I guess he downvoted you @mxdi9i7